# How do I add image assets at runtime?

Tags: aframe

I've got an entity like this:

```
<a-entity id="entity1" 
    position="0 0 -1"
    geometry="primitive: plane; width: 1"
    material="src: #myTexture;  opacity:0.9; transparent:true;">
```

I'm attempting to assign a new Base64 image string like this:

```
myTexture.setAttribute('src','data:image/png;base64,xxx');
```

This seems to work in that `myTexture` appears to contain the new image. However, `entity1` is not updated with that new material.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Modify the entity rather than the stuff in `<a-assets>`. The asset management system is for preloading and caching. If you are setting assets dynamically, you can set them inline.

`el.setAttribute('material', 'src', 'url(data:image/png;base64,xxx)')`.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify:

Comment: should that be: myTexture.setAttribute('src',url('data:image/png;base64,xxx'))?

Comment: I've modified the answer. url() is part of the string, not a function. Oh I just caught to modify the entity, not the asset item.